# Information on train travel across the USA

Tags: usa, trains

I am interested in taking the train from seattle to new york.  How long would it take?  How much would it cost for a sleeping compartment?

Comment: [Rome2Rio](https://www.rome2rio.com/map/Seattle/New-York) says 2 days 18 hrs and gives a cost range.

Comment: Have you done any research?

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please note that this is not a discussion forum, but a Q&A site, and one of the basic expectations of Stack Exchange is that you demonstrate your initial research efforts. I strongly encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help] for additional guidance.

Answer (score 5):

The Man in Seat 61 provides [a guide to train travel in the US](https://www.seat61.com/UnitedStates.htm). You can [look up schedules and fares on Amtrak's website](https://www.amtrak.com/home.html), as prices vary depending on your dates.

Long-distance train travel in the US takes a very long time, and if you want a sleeper, the ticket is usually more expensive than an equivalent airline ticket. By all means do it for the sake of the journey—some of the routes have extraordinary scenery—but consider that it may not be the most efficient option in terms of cost and time.